# Issue when promoting a second server as domain on R2 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-controller

I'm in an odd situation here.

I've upgraded my network to a 2008 domain from a 2003 with out any issue, this works fine and all the FSMO are in one DC,

I was about to install a second domain on a 2008R2 and this error is coming up again and again.

I The problem is I keep getting an area telling me that I need to run `adprep /domainPrep /forestPrep`, but when I run it on the first DC, it tells me this has already been run and updated and it is aborted. Does anyone have any ideas on why I can't add a Server 2008 machine as a domain controller?

Comment: Why do you want a second domain?

Comment: Well, obviously this is in a test network and initialy I've done the migration from 2003 to a 2008 Data center and now I want to move everything to a 2008R2 server.

Comment: Come on OBVIOUSLY! He did specify that in his question...

Comment: Mouradb, that is not obvious.  If you don't write it, we don't know it.

Comment: I;m lost now!! what are you missing Waldo?? I think teh discription says it all!!

Comment: Mouradb - your phrasing might be interpreted as a bit hostile, particularly toward people trying to help you.  If you try to be clear, precise, and thorough about your environment as well as the error, that will get you the best results.

Comment: So are you trying to add a second domain to the the forest? New tree? New forest?

Comment: Chris hello, 
adding the new dc to the existing domain/forest, this will be a secondary DC on a VM

Comment: Did you make the 2008 DC a global catalog server before demoting the 2003 boxes?

Answer (score 1):

Did you get the adprep program and data files from the R2 CD?

The files included with $OLDER_VERSION_OF_WINDOWS don't work so well with newer versions.

Comment: Yes I did run this from the 2008R2 CD and no luck,
taken the second server off the domain and put it back but still same issue,